# SharePoint 2010: specific start date for an Event reverts to midnight on save

Tags: calendar

I have a list based on a content type that inherits from events. This list has two relevant fields:

• Start Date
• End Date

I add a new item to the list, setting the start time to 3:00pm and the end time to 3:05pm and then save the event.

When I click edit on the same event, SharePoint now shows the start time as being 12:00am. SharePoint seems only to be saving the date component of Start Date, but it saves the date and time component of End Date. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

In Event [Content Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479905%28v=office.14%29.aspx) fields *Start Time* and *End Time* are both declared with [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.utilities.datetimeformat%28v=office.14%29.aspx) as `DateTime` .

*Start Time* and *End Time* fields are dependent on the field *All Day Event*

### *All Day Event* is unchecked

date & time could be specified for *Start Time* and *End Time* fields

### *All Day Event* is checked

in that case only date part could be specified in form for *Start Time* and *End Time* fields. The following code demonstrates how time part is updated when *All Day Event* is checked

```
ListItem["StartDate"] = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day, 0, 0, 0, (System.Globalization.Calendar) new GregorianCalendar());
ListItem["EndDate"] = new DateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, endDate.Day, 23, 59, 0, (System.Globalization.Calendar) new GregorianCalendar());
```

Comment: The problem turned out to be due to the Template I used to create the List. I was setting it up originally using the SPListTemplateType.GenericList but I should have been using the SPListTemplateType.Events. When I use the latter, and I openSharePoint Manager to observe the Fields belonging to the List, the SchemaXml showed the following for StartDate:   <FieldRefs> <FieldRef Name="fAllDayEvent" RefType="AllDayEvent" /> </FieldRefs> Whereas before, using the generic template, there was no field reference to the All Day Event, which is why my dates were changing.